# HTML5 controls from Html5Asp - trouble with video

Tags: html

I have been experimenting with these new 'HTML5:' controls and I'm not sure if there are better options out there or I am just too new with all of this to understand basic syntax.  Here is my code and I have success with Maplink and EmailLink, but for the last hour I have tried to Google the answer for the video one.  No matter what I try, I cannot define the source file anywhere without it failing.  I wish there was a site that just gave you the usage syntax with these controls, but I can't seem to find one.  The Html5Asp web site does offer examples on some, but only a few.

```
<div>        
    <html5:MapLink runat="server" ID="lnkMap" Text="Directions to Hodas"
    Start="3022 Hudson Road, Erie, PA 20540 "
    Finish="3421 Emerson Avenue, Erie, PA, 16508" />    
    <br />
    <html5:EmailLink runat="server" ID="lnkEmail" Subject="Easy to Email This" Body="I am testing HTML5." 
    MailTo="bhodas@curtze.com" CC="tony@curtze.com" Text="Send Email"/>
    <br />
    <html5:Video ID="Video1" width="320" height="240" runat="server" ControlsOn="true">
        <Source>
        </Source>
    </html5:Video>    
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the src and type attribute in the source tag

```
<source src="__VIDEO__.MP4" type="video/mp4" />
```

Here is a great [resource](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)

Comment: Thank you for the resource - great site!  I did try to place the code inside the source tags, but it doesn't run.  However, once I switched from 'Html5:video' to just 'video', even though Intellisense didn't like it it still ran fine :)